# Cannot run the Unity 8 openclipart scope example

Tags: unity, application-development, unity-dash, ubuntu-sdk, scopes

Following the instructions of [this](http://developer.ubuntu.com/scopes/tutorials/unity-8-scope-example-openclipart/) page, I have installed the Ubuntu SDK and downloaded the tutorials source code.

The openclipart scope builds correctly, but I have a runtime error:

```
$ unity-scope-tool src/openclipart-scope.ini 
scoperegistry: no remote registry configured, only local scopes will be available
RegistryObject::ScopeProcess::exec(): Process for scope: "openclipart-scope" started
file:///usr/share/unity8/Dash/DashContent.qml:100: TypeError: Cannot read property 'loaded' of null
file:///usr/share/unity8/ScopeTool.qml:77:31: Unable to assign [undefined] to scopes_ng::Scope*
file:///usr/share/unity8/ScopeTool.qml:149:23: Unable to assign null to QString

(unity-scope-tool:6243): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/Ubuntu/Components/Themes/Ambiance/TabBarStyle.qml:303: TypeError: Property 'select' of object QQuickRepeater(0x2711350) is not a function
file:///usr/share/unity8/Dash/DashContent.qml:100: TypeError: Cannot read property 'loaded' of null
Need to use QMirServerApplication
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Unity 8 (and `unity-scope-tool` by extension) are designed so they can run under both Mir and X11, there is some ambiguity in the dependencies.  The error you got indicates that it is trying to use the Mir backend.

You should be able to fix the problem by installing the `unity8-fake-env` package, which provides some of the needed APIs to run the tool under X:

```
sudo apt-get install unity8-fake-env
```